# How to make a child not expand the width of a flex container parent?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using display:flex on a container and have a child heading define it's width. I'd like some paragraph text under it but I don't want that paragraph to stretch the width of the flex container. How can I achieve this?

```css
.main {
 display:flex;
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
}

.left {
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
}

.right {
 flex:0 0 auto;
 position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div class='left'>
    <h1>SOME TITLE</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla commodo pretium dolor, non vestibulum erat ullamcorper a. Cras ac bibendum nibh. Sed eget lectus quis lorem tempus pulvinar.</p>
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
    <h1>ANOTHER TITLE</h1>
    <p>This paragraph should break into lines and expand vertically instead of stretching the parent div horizontally.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of `flex: 0 0 auto`, have you tried `flex: 0 1 auto`?

Comment: That will make the header break lines too which is not quite what I want.

Comment: Give the `p` element a large `margin`. You could also put the `p` element in it's own `div` with a width and set that `div`s `margin` to `0 auto`

Comment: Oh wait! Maybe set the parents `box-sizing` to `border-box`? This should ignore any added width from wherever.

Comment: Set a width on the paragraph. Try `.right > p { width: 50% }`.

Comment: Border-box seems to do nothing and setting the width of the paragraph to 50% simply maintains the expanded width of the container, but makes the paragraph half of that. There ought to be a way to prevent a child from being treated as a flex-item and just act like a normal element.

Comment: The only flex items in your code are `.right` and `.left`. The heading and paragraph are not flex items. They are standard block elements.

Comment: `.left` is not allowed to shrink because you have it set to `flex-shrink: 0`. If you enable shrink,  the text will wrap, but you said earlier you don't want that option.

Comment: I want the .right container width be defined by the heading in it and have the paragraph text in it wrap into lines. The .left should do what it currently does, use up all the remaining width in the .main. I'm a rookie, maybe flex isn't the right answer to this but it did its job before I decided I wanted longer paragraph text in the .right. Enabling shrink will make the header wrap and I don't want that, but maybe that can be fixed?

Comment: I meant `.right` in my last comment, not `.left`.

Comment: Maybe a step forward? https://jsfiddle.net/xL71ntvh/

Comment: Yes! I'm a little embarrassed to say it but I was not aware of the white-space:nowrap option on the heading. Putting an exaggerated flex-shrink value of 100 on .right and white-space:nowrap on the heading seem to achieve what I want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting an exaggerated flex-shrink value of 100 on .right and white-space:nowrap on the heading did the trick. Thanks to [Michael_B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3597276/michael-b).

```css
.main {
 display:flex;
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
}

.left {
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
}

.right {
 flex:0 100 auto;
 position:relative;
}

.right h1 {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div class='left'>
    <h1>SOME TITLE</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla commodo pretium dolor, non vestibulum erat ullamcorper a. Cras ac bibendum nibh. Sed eget lectus quis lorem tempus pulvinar.</p>
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
    <h1>ANOTHER TITLE</h1>
    <p>This paragraph should break lines and expand vertically instead of stretching the parent div horizontally.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```